# Edit a CSV column through another column

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk

I have a Bash script which prompts for input in order to edit a CSV column:

```
echo X, as recorded in TIFF header, to be removed:
read X
sed -i "" "/^[^,]*_f_[^,_]*,/s/,$X /,f. /
    s/,$X /,/" $pathToCSV".csv"
```

Now I want to avoid the manual, one-at-a-time inputting and instead use another column of the CSV (column C) which includes the value `X` to edit this first column. This way, I can batch generate these CSVs from TIFF headers and not have to input `X` (which differs from one CSV to the next) each time.

I looked around and tried a few things, including:

```
X=$(awk 'NR == 2 {print $3}' $pathToCSV".csv")
sed -i "" "/^[^,]*_f_[^,_]*,/s/,$X /,f. /
    s/,$X /,/" $pathToCSV".csv"
```

This doesn't work and the output still includes `X`. (The column C includes the same value in all its rows, and I'm using C2 arbitrarily.)

**Update 1**:

As requested, I'm pasting part of my CSV here:

```
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0001_a_1.tif   Si Ar 695 Front Board Outside   Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0002_a_1a.tif  Si Ar 695 Front Board Outside   Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0003_b_000.tif Si Ar 695 Front Board Inside    Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0009_b_003v.tif    Si Ar 695 Flyleaf 003v  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0010_f_001r.tif    Si Ar 695 001r  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0060_y_001r.tif    Si Ar 695 Flyleaf 001r  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0070_y_999.tif Si Ar 695 Back Board Inside Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0071_z_1.tif   Si Ar 695 Back Board Outside    Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0072_z_1a.tif  Si Ar 695 Back Board Outside    Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0073_z_2.tif   Si Ar 695 Spine Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0074_z_3.tif   Si Ar 695 Fore edge Si Ar 695
```

Instead of inputting "Si Ar 695" manually (and some other value for a different CSV), the third column should be used to remove the repeat value from the front of the second column.

**Update 2**:

The `awk` command below that @anubhava suggested works perfectly:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF>2 && NR==1{s=$3} {sub("^" s "[[:blank:]]+", "", $2)} 1' $pathToCSV".csv"
```

However, I just remembered the `sed` command I had previously, i.e.

```
sed -i "" "/^[^,]*_f_[^,_]*,/s/,$X /,f. /
    s/,$X /,/" $pathToCSV".csv"
```

would prepend my second column with `f.` whenever the file name in the first column included a `_f_`. I think this should be a regex adjustment, but I'm struggling with implementing that in the `awk` command above.

This is the input:

```
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0010_f_001r.tif    Si Ar 695 001r  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0011_f_001v.tif    Si Ar 695 001v  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0012_f_002r.tif    Si Ar 695 002r  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0013_f_002v.tif    Si Ar 695 002v  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0014_f_003ar.tif   Si Ar 695 003r  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0015_f_003av.tif   Si Ar 695 003v  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0016_f_004br.tif   Si Ar 695 004r  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0017_f_004bv.tif   Si Ar 695 004v  Si Ar 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0018_f_005r.tif    Si Ar 695 005r  Si Ar 695
```

And this the desired output:

```
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0010_f_001r.tif    f. 001r Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0011_f_001v.tif    f. 001v Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0012_f_002r.tif    f. 002r Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0013_f_002v.tif    f. 002v Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0014_f_003ar.tif   f. 003r Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0015_f_003av.tif   f. 003v Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0016_f_004br.tif   f. 004r Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0017_f_004bv.tif   f. 004v Sinai Arabic 695
/Volumes/Masters/DLTempSecure/EMEL_SLDP/201808/tiffs/arabic_0695/sld_arb0695_0018_f_005r.tif    f. 005r Sinai Arabic 695
```

I would appreciate any help with **Update 2**!

Comment: Consider posting the pathToCSV fle (at least few lines if it's very big).

Comment: If your CSV is comma separated then `Si Ar 695` is 2nd column not 3rd in your sample data

Comment: I didn't paste the first column. There's a first column that's the file path of the TIFF.

Comment: It would be better to show correct input data in question otherwise you'll get wrong answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==2{s=$2} NR>1{sub("^" s "[[:blank:]]+", "")} 1' file.csv
```

```
$2,$3
Front Board Outside,Si Ar 695
Front Board Inside,Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 001r,Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 001v,Si Ar 695
```

---

As per your pastebin link you may use this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NF>2 && NR==1{s=$3} {sub("^" s "[[:blank:]]+", "", $2)} 1' file
```

---

**Update 2:**

As per your latest update, you will need to use following awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF>2 && NR==1{s=$3} {sub("^" s "[[:blank:]]+", "", $2)} $1 ~ /_f_/{$2 = "f. " $2} 1' file.csv
```

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't; the output is still the same. Did you get the result above from the ```awk``` here or pasted mine? And shouldn't ```NR==2{s=$2}``` be ```$3```? (Although I tried both with the same result.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I created a CSV with the sample input that you've used and exactly the same ```awk```, but for some reason I'm still not getting what you've already got. Can it be my ```awk``` version? It's 20070501.

Comment: This worked (with the delimiter changed back to comma)! Thanks so much. Can we make one modification to the command though? I'm going to explain it in my **Update 2**.

Comment: I can surely update it but can you edit your question again and show few lines of sample data that have `_f_` in 1st column. Don't forget to include expected output.

Comment: Done! These are the _f_ rows from the CSV; the other rows (which include _a_, _b_, _y_, or _z_ as you can see under **Update 1**) shouldn't get prepended by anything.

Comment: ok try this: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF>2 && NR==1{s=$3} {sub("^" s "[[:blank:]]+", "", $2)} $1 ~ /_f_/{$2 = "f. " $2} 1' file.csv`

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Using your raw data (https://pastebin.com/V9Jg4icj) and Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --nidx --fs tab cut -x -f 1 then put -S '$2=gsub($2,"^.+[0-9] ","")' input
```

You will have

```
Front Board Outside     Si Ar 695
Front Board Outside     Si Ar 695
Front Board Inside      Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 001r    Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 001v    Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 002r    Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 002v    Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 003r    Si Ar 695
Flyleaf 003v    Si Ar 695
001r    Si Ar 695
001v    Si Ar 695
002r    Si Ar 695
002v    Si Ar 695
003r    Si Ar 695
003v    Si Ar 695
004r    Si Ar 695
004v    Si Ar 695
005r    Si Ar 695
005v    Si Ar 695
006r    Si Ar 695
006v    Si Ar 695
007r    Si Ar 695
007v    Si Ar 695
008r    Si Ar 695
008v    Si Ar 695
009r    Si Ar 695
...    ...
...    ...
```

If you want a CSV output

```
mlr --n2c --ifs tab cut -x -f 1 then put -S '$2=gsub($2,"^.+[0-9] ","")' input
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't set it up on my machine. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: @KayGee what's you operative system? What's the error you have?

Comment: It's a Mac. I think I didn't follow the ReadMe instructions correctly.

Comment: @KayGee I'm not a mac user. I think the simplest way is to use homebrew installation:  `brew update` and than `brew install miller`. If you do not have homebrew http://osxdaily.com/2018/03/07/how-install-homebrew-mac-os/

Comment: Thanks. I installed it with ```brew```, but the same problem: it just doesn't affect the output.

Comment: @KayGee I have seen your raw data and edited my answer. Please try again with the new command

Comment: I get a blank file (or when I print it, a huge blank in my Terminal).

Comment: @KayGee there is something stange. For me it works good http://youtu.be/GE4Tm8ner4U?hd=1